# htaccess rewrite rule for url varible as parent folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I already create a .htaccess in my folder and would like to make the **URL:**

`www.example/good/page`

**toward:**

`www.example/page?type=good`

**my current document is written as:**

`RewriteRule ^(\w+)$\/page page.php?type=$1 [NC,L]`

but it didn't work, and I don't know how to check it is correct or not

would anyone able to provide some example for that?
thanks!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^type/([^/]*)$ /page?type=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your rewite engine is on, and it is rewriting the base. Change your code like the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/page?$ "page.php?type=$1" [L,QSA]
```

And then your rewrite rule must look like this.

The RewriteRule basically means that if the request is done that matches `^/?([^/]+)/page?$` (matches any URL except the server root), it will be rewritten as `page.php?type=$1` which means a request for `page.php` be rewritten as `page.php?type=good`).

`QSA` means that if there's a query string passed with the original URL, it will be appended to the rewrite (`example.com/good/page?id=2` will be rewritten as `page.php?type=good&id=2`.

`L` means if the rule matches, don't process any more RewriteRules below this one.

Try this and let me know. Accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, though I still cannot get the result I want.
I'm wondering if the directory of example.com/good/page.html is truly exist would it effect the result?

the htaccess now is like this:
<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</files>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/page?$ "page.php?type=$1" [L,QSA]

Comment: @MichaelC Please update the question with your current version of the .htaccess file. Because my answer is tested okay. Your rewrite condition must be making it behave differently.